# Реализовать разные варианты оформления элемента

Tags: html, css

Есть заготовка, как довести её до состояние как на изображении [image]и сделать остальные два варианта?

```css
.sho_bq-background {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.sho_bq-background:before {
  color: #ff0054;
  content: "\1F676";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: -.4em;
}

.sho_bq-background:after {
  color: #ff0054;
  position: relative;
  content: "\1F677";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  vertical-align: -0.6em;
}

cite span:first-child {
  color: #aeadad;
  font-style: normal;
}

cite span:last-child {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="sho_bq-background">
<p>«Идеалами, освещавшими мой путь и сообщавшими мне смелость и мужество, были доброта, красота и истина. Без чувства солидарности с теми, кто разделяет мои убеждения, без преследования вечно  неуловимого объективного в искусстве и в науке жизнь показалась бы мне абсолютно пустой»</p>
<cite><span>Автор цитаты: </span><span>Альберт Эйнштейн</span></cite>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Позиционировать элементы относительно `blockquote`:

```css
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

blockquote:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  
  color: #ff0054;
  content: "\1F676";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: -.4em;
}

blockquote:after {
  color: #ff0054;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -10px;
  content: "\1F677";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  vertical-align: -0.6em;
}

cite span:first-child {
  color: #aeadad;
  font-style: normal;
}

cite span:last-child {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
<p>«Идеалами, освещавшими мой путь и сообщавшими мне смелость и мужество, были доброта, красота и истина. Без чувства солидарности с теми, кто разделяет мои убеждения, без преследования вечно  неуловимого объективного в искусстве и в науке жизнь показалась бы мне абсолютно пустой»</p>
<cite><span>Автор цитаты: </span><span>Альберт Эйнштейн</span></cite>
</blockquote>
```

Здесь также, как и в первом примере, только нужно изменить цвет элементов и добавить `background: white`:

```css
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

cite span:first-child {
  color: #aeadad;
  font-style: normal;
}

cite span:last-child {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

blockquote:before {
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  color: gray;
  content: "\1F676";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

blockquote:after {
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -10px;
  content: "\1F677";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
<p>«Идеалами, освещавшими мой путь и сообщавшими мне смелость и мужество, были доброта, красота и истина. Без чувства солидарности с теми, кто разделяет мои убеждения, без преследования вечно  неуловимого объективного в искусстве и в науке жизнь показалась бы мне абсолютно пустой»</p>
<cite><span>Автор цитаты: </span><span>Альберт Эйнштейн</span></cite>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Хорошо ответил!

Comment: круто, а как прозрачные кавычки с серым контуром сделать?

Comment: @BlackFire, вряд ли их можно сделать с помощью CSS-символов, но можно попробовать сделать их с SVG или с помощью вставки картинки. Можно задать отдельный вопрос по этому поводу, постараюсь ответить